# Is there a plan to include Android PdfRenderer in a support library?

Tags: android, compatibility, pdfrenderer

In Android 5.0, Google introduced the PdfRenderer class, which is great for rendering PDFs. The problem is that it is only available with minSDK 21. 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfRenderer.html

How can i find out if there are plans to include this class in a support library?

Answer (score 5):

> How can i find out if there are plans to include this class in a support library?

You can get a job with Google, then ask them. Google does not generally make pronouncements about what will happen when with respect to the Android SDK, including the Android Support package.

That being said, since [that class relies upon native code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/graphics/java/android/graphics/pdf/PdfRenderer.java), it is unlikely that it will be added to the Android Support package.